beginner writing code for web scrapping link,text,images from multiple webpages using selenium and python and store in excel
This is the code I have written:
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# List of URLs to scrape
urls = ["https://www.monolithai.com/blog/4-ways-ai-is-changing-the-packaging-industry"
,"https://mitsubishisolutions.com/the-role-of-artificial-intelligence-in-smart-packaging-lines"
, "https://thedatascientist.com/how-artificial-intelligence-is-revolutionizing-the-packaging-industry/"
," https://packagingeurope.com/comment/ai-and-the-future-of-packaging/9665.article"]

# Initialize the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Use appropriate WebDriver for your browser
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

# Initialize empty lists to store scraped data

all_text = []
all_images = []
all_links = []

# Iterate over each URL and scrape text, images, and links
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)

    body= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,'body')))
    
# Scrape text
    page_text = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
    all_text.append(page_text)
    
# Scrape images
    images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
    image_urls = [img.get_attribute('src') for img in images]
    all_images.append(image_urls)
    
# Scrape links
    links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    link_urls = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]
    all_links.append(link_urls)

# Close the WebDriver when finished 
#driver.quit() 

# Create a DataFrame from the scraped data
data = {
    'URL': urls,
    'Text': all_text,
    'Images': all_images,
    'Links': all_links
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
df.to_excel('scraped_data.xlsx', index=False)

getting the following error:

DevTools listening on
ws://127.0.0.1:56991/devtools/browser/8be11b91-e7ec-4f18-949e-7319a4341af5
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\PRADEEP
BIRARE\Desktop\web3.py", line 29, in <module>     page_text =
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text  AttributeError:
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_tag_name' PS
C:\Users\PRADEEP BIRARE>


You seem to have a bunch of unterminated string literals in your code, as you should be able to see from the code highlighting. Would you like to check and repost your code as a [mre]? Maybe you should use # comments for your comments.

find_element_by_tag_name is not a valid function, tags are not unique so there could be multiple. you need to use find_elements_by_tag_name like you have elsewhere and just access the first item in the list

The error stems from deprecated find_element_by_* methods in Selenium 4.3.0+.
Fix: Replace them with find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body') (similarly for images/links).
Consider closing the WebDriver after use with driver.quit().
